# Do previous versions of .NET framework come with every new version of windows?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

What versions of .NET framework are in Window XP, 7  or 8?Some programs require a framework on Windows 8, but not on 7. It seems like there is no backward compatibility of .NET versions between Windows. Or they are hidden and I should activate it?

Comment: Certainly on Windows 8, .NET 3.5 has to be added as a feature and 2.0 has to be installed manually. I believe Windows 7 had 3.5 installed by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all previous version aren't installed by default on a system, though at least one version is hidden to default users and can be installed by accessing:

```
Turn Windows features on or off
```

in the Control Panel (Windows 7). If you really want older versions, you will have to download and install them.